# Parse SQL Output

Tags: sql, powershell

I execute a SQL Query, the output is of `System.Data.DataRow` type inside `$rawdata`:

```
MachineName           : BLAH
AccountNameWithDomain : Blah\demo
DistinguishedName     : CN=demo,OU=desktop,OU=A00,OU=Sec,DC=my,DC=domain
```

From PowerShell, I need to get from `$rawdata` only the data where `DC=my,DC=domain`.

Comment: Hi @dokho , welcome to SO or sort of ... Can you show us your steps, please?

Comment: Actually it looks like it was simpler than what I thought $rawdata |Where DistinguishedName -match $variable seems to do the trick. I was trying to use contains but looks like match is doing what I need.

Comment: @dokho, can you provide your answer , please?

Comment: Can you filter the result set with appropriate `WHERE... LIKE...` clause on the Sql Server? As a best practice, unnecessary data shouldn't be sent to the client at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$rawdata` contains an object or a list of objects, so you should be able to filter on the objects' properties. Something like this should work:

```
$rawdata | Where-Object { $_.DistinguishedName -like '*DC=my,DC=domain' }
```